# SoundManager2 (audio player): retrieve the ID of the link that was clicked

Tags: javascript, audio, onclick, soundmanager2

I use the API to create my SoundManager audio playList. I followed this tutorial:
[totorial](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/du-son-dans-vos-pages-web-avec-soundmanager-2/tp-un-lecteur-audio-3)

When I click on a link (a song from my player), in the method play, I display a div that contains links (a), and I call upon the method **voter ()**.

```
onplay : // Quand on fait "play"
        function() {
        var t=titre.toString();
        document.getElementById("informations").style.visibility="visible";
        voter();
                                    },
```

In **voter()** method I want when I click on one of the  of my div, I recovered the song.

```
function voter(){

    $('#informations .container .votes_main .votes_gray .votes_buttons a').click(function () {
        alert(current);
    });
}
```

the problem is: when I click on the first, I recovered well its id (0) in an alert. But if later I click on the second, I have two alert, which contain the value of the id (1) of the second, and when I click again on the first, I would have 3 alert containing the value of the current song (0), and so on ....

How do I have to click each, and one alert that contains both the id of the song in court

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem and I share it with you:

```
function voter(){

$('#informations .container .votes_main .votes_gray .votes_buttons a').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){
alert(current);
});
}
```